# Expected value for random variables based on Poisson distribution

Tags: expected-value, poisson-distribution

I have to calculate the limit of the sequence $E((\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}})^+)$, where $X_n$ is Poi(n) and $\xi^+$ means "Maximum of $\xi$ and $0$". I get $e^2/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and I am not sure that this is correct. My calculation is straightforward, using Stirling formula at the end. It is rather long so I don't really want to place it here. Perhaps somebody has a better idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $(Y_n)$ be i.i.d. with $Poss(1)$ distribution. The $X_n$ has same distribution as $Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$. Now just apply CLT to find the limit.

You will need the following: If $Z_n \to Z$ in distribution and $EZ_n^{2}$ is bounded the $EZ_n \to $EZ$.

Comment: Thanks, I had this idea. But I have here this + (maximum with 0), what can I do about it?

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 If $U_n \to U$ in distribution the $U_n^{+} \to U^{+}$ in distribution  and $EU_n^{+} \to EU^{+}$  if the second moments are bounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!